# How can I access bulk-edit button "bulkedit_all"? Python / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate JIRA tasks but struggling to access bulkedit option after JQL filter. After accessing the correct sceen I am stuck at this point:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YwyZ.png)

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="aui-list">
    <h5>Bulk Change:</h5>
    <ul class="aui-list-sectionaui-first aui-last">
        <li class="aui-list-item active">
            <a class="aui-list-item-link" id="bulkedit_all" href="/secure/views/bulkedit/BulkEdit1!default.jspa?reset=true&amp;tempMax=4">all 4 issue(s)</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My Python code:**

```
bulkDropdown = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='aui-list']//aui-list[@class='aui-list-item.active']").click()
```

Comment: Solution: This helped. `bulkEdit = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bulkedit_all"))).click()`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following xpath -

```
bulkDropdown = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//li/a[@id='bulkedit_all']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you want has an ID, you should use that unless you find that it's not unique on the page.

```
browser.find_element_by_id("bulkedit_all").click()
```

You will likely need to add a wait for clickable since from the screenshot it looks like a popup or tooltip of some kind. See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for more info on the different waits available.